# Get javascript var from webview to android var

Tags: javascript, android, html, web, webview

I am trying get a var from a webview but I only can modify like this:

```
browser.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('login').value = 'something';");
```

but I need get any js var like this :

```
String myAndroidvar = browser.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('login').value");
```

but this syntax is incorrect, I need the correct method.

Comment: Use JSoup library for web scraping. I think it's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a javaScriptInterface to you webview. See [this blog for a decent description](http://android-puremvc-ormlite.blogspot.nl/2011/07/using-java-script-in-android-webview.html).
You can also get stuff from javascript by calling an interface function you defined using:

```
web.loadUrl("javascript: window.jsinterface.getValue(document.getElementById('login').value)");
```